# WPF Localization -( wont find .resx files)

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I'm very new to WPF and I want to be able to change my language at Runtime. I was googling a lot and I found this : [Localization of a WPF app - the simple approach](https://codinginfinity.me/post/2015-05-10/localization_of_a_wpf_app_the_simple_approach)

I copied his .cs and I'm pretty sure I understand what he did. However, he didn't publish the XAML Code for the example and I don't know what to do.
I tried:

```
<Button Name="menuBtn2" Content="{local:Loc menuBtn2}">
```

but he won't find 'menuBtn2' in my .resx (there is no exception he just won't find it)

can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You haven't mentioned enough to find the problem. The code in the link works fine. Are you using the default resource file? Or if you've created another, is it accessible? Are there no errors on the output window?

Comment: yes i had my own .resx. now i tried with the default one and it works, but i have only one language now? only the default .resx or am i missing something. how can i add my own .resx files :S

Comment: For your own resx files, try using resourceFileName.menuBtn2.

Comment: I find localisation often means only of part of the strings. I've worked for german companies who have adopted English for most of their UI. You also have to switch out branding as well as language. The way I do both is with resource dictionaries and make the text of buttons and textblocks use a dynamicresource. Merge your French resource dictionary and everything changes to French. Merge Spanish and everything changes to Spanish. You can even make these uncompiled XAML so clients can edit strings when they find their Spanish is better than mine.

Comment: that sounds a little bit too complicated for me :D. i think i will stick with that method... so back to trying i guess. but before i start is it even possible to switch.resx with this method? i shouldve never started WPF:/.

Comment: I think the name should be e.g. .resx.fr (for french) and it automatically chooses that resource file  according to fr culture

Comment: oh, i renamed it into .resx.en now and it autogenerated a designer and i think this is the way it should work. now how i only need to update the TransitionSource.CurrentCulture. do you have an idea how i can do that :S